# PHP Amazon Ses as an abstract class gives use fatal error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm using the Amazon Simple Email Service and am trying to implement it as an abstract class so that I can simply use it throughout as needed.

**Problem**

The problem occurs with the use, I cannot work out how to require the files and classes needed to use `Ses` as an abstract class without incurring errors.

```
require 'lib/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;

abstract class simpleemail {

    function sendSesEmail($to, $subject, $body, $bodyHtml){

        try {   
            $client = SesClient::factory(array(
                'key' => "",
                'secret' => "",
                'region' => Region::US_EAST_1
            ));

            $send = $client->sendEmail(array(
                'Source' => 'Name <no-reply@contact.com>',
                'Destination' => array('ToAddresses' => array($to)),
                'Message' => array('Subject' => array('Data' => $subject), 'Body' => array('Html' => array('Data' => $bodyHtml)))));

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Messages**

`Fatal error: Class 'Aes\Ses\SesClient' not found in ....`

I have tried changing the `use` to require but then get:

```
require 'lib/aws/Aws/Common/Enum/Region.php';
require 'lib/aws/Aws/Ses/SesClient.php';
```

`Fatal error: 'SesClient' not found in ...`

**Solution?**

How can I use/require the files I need to get this working inside an abstract class?

Comment: Put `use ...` outside classes, on the begining of the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
abstract class simpleemail
{
    public function sendSesEmail()
    {
        use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;
        use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
        //...
    }
}
```

`use` statements are, basically, imports, that are processed at compile-time, so they can't be scoped. They have to move to the outer scope (outside of the class).
If you want to scope them, you'll have to *either*, manually `require` them, or use `class_alias`.
[Check my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764841/why-use-class-alisases/17942310#17942310) for more details. Even more details can, as ever, be found [on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Side-notes:

- Please, follow the coding standards as described by [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/1/). They're not official, but Zend, Symfony... all major players, in fact, subscribe to them.
- Please get in the habbit of *always* specifying the accessmodifiers (`public`, `protected` and `private`)
- When creating instances like you do `$client = SesClient::factory`, assign them to a property, to only create the instance once. At the moment, each method call creates the same instance over and over again. That's bad
- When using properties: [include them in the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17696356/1230836)!
- You're calling `sendEmail` on an instance, and assign the return value to `$send`. You don't check the return value, nor do you return it. Either ignore the return value, or return it, so it can be checked!
- Never use `require`, use `require_once` if you have to. Using `require` can cause errors when executing the same block of code twice: redeclaring functions/classes. If time is of the essence, you could opt for `require` (as `require_once` causes more overhead), but you have to know what you're doing.
- don't `require` an autoloader, use [`spl_autoloader_register`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)
- Remember: Abstract classes can't be instantiated, only their children... children can also override the methods declared in the abstract class. Declare critical methods as `final`

So, the answer:

```
use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
abstract class simpleemail
{
    protected $client = null;
    final public function sendSesEmail()
    {
        $client = $this->getClient();//lazy-loads the client instance
        return $client->sendEmail(/* ... */);//return the result
    }
    //lazy-loader
    protected function getClient()
    {
        if ($this->client === null)
        {
            $this->client = SesClient::factory(array(
                'key' => "",
                'secret' => "",
                'region' => Region::US_EAST_1
            ));
        }
        return $this->client;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I just do the `use` I get countless errors about other uses failing?

Comment: @Silver89: That's because you have to register an autoloader (using `spl_autoloader_register`) that can resolve the namespaces to their respective paths. Since you're using `require` to include an autoloader function (probably an old-school `__autoload` function), there is no autoloader available at compile time. Honestly: register an autoloader _before_ creating a single instance (or create an instance, that registers one of its methods as an autoloader). Also start the file containing this class with `namespace YourNameSpace\If\A\NS\Applies;`

Comment: Just read through the documentation on working with namespaces (and make sure you're running PHP>=5.3. If not, namespaces are not available

Comment: Yes I have PHP>=5.3. The problem I'm having is the location of the files, they are not `Aws/Ses/SesClient` but `lib/aws/Aws/Ses/SesClient` do I use namespace for this? If I use: `use Aws\Ses\SesClient` then all of the `use` inside that file get messed up?

Comment: @JeremyLindblom: spl_autoload_register works with an __autoload stack. just register both. rtfm, the link is in the answer. as long as the autoloaders don't return false, php will call them one by one.

Comment: @Silver89: just add the lib directory to your include path: `set_include_path('/path/to/lib'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path())`